# Make chartjs re-render once

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have a couple of charts (done with chart.js) and was able to animate them when they're in viewport. In the code below, fullyVisible() is to check whether a chart is in viewport, and if so re-render it. The issue is that, with this code, the chart keeps re-rendering with each scroll until it's totally out of the viewport. My question is whether it's possible to render the chart only once.

```
$(window).on("resize scroll", function(){ 
  if ($('#myChart').fullyVisible()) {
    chart = new Chart(ctx, config); 
    chart.render();
   };    

  if ($('#myChart1').fullyVisible()) {
    chart1 = new Chart(ctx1, config1); 
    chart1.render();
   }; 
});
```

Comment: add a boolean in the "fullyVisible" -> if is fully visible -> set the flag "alreadyRender" to true and render the graph. So if is already visible and the boolean is true -> you already render it. When is not fully visible -> set the boolean to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a boolean flag:

```
let isRendered = false;
```

… and test it:

```
if (!isRendered && $('#myChart').isFullyVisible()) {
    chart = new Chart(ctx, config); 
    chart.render();

    isRendered = !isRendered;
}

if (isRendered && $('#myChart').isOutOfView()) {
    chart.destroy();
    chart = null;

    isRendered = !isRendered;
}
```

… or alternatively you could check, whether `chart` exists:

```
let chart = null;

if (!chart && $('#myChart').isFullyVisible()) {
   chart = new Chart(ctx, config); 
   chart.render();
}

if (chart && $('#myChart').isOutOfView()) {
    chart.destroy();
    chart = null;
}
```

All tests will fire the probably expensive visibility test only when needed.

---

As a side note, it would be better to cache your selectors, so that you don't need to re-query them on each scroll/resize event:

```
const chartCanvas = $('#chart');

$(window).on('resize scroll', function☮ { 
    if (chartCanvas.fullyVisible()) {}
});
```